# Resizing Objects for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image: The Login Page]

I want to put the login boxes in the center. Don't know how to do it in the bootstrap. can anyone say it is to be done.

Below is the code that I have written. Please Correct me

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
      <h3><strong>OR</strong></h3>
  </div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <form class="form-signin" style="text-align:center" role="form">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in to Continue</h2>           
        <div class="col-lg-7"><input type="email" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Domain ID" autofocus required></div>
        <div class="col-lg-7"><input type="password" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Password" required></div>
        <p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to center the Login Div, simply follow the basic bootstrap grid standard.
The grid is divided into 12 columns. To center a div that spans 6 columns , you need it to be 3 columns away from the start very left of the page. i.e col-sm-offset-3
I modified your code to reflect the changes

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="starter-template text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
        <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
    <h3>
        <strong>OR</strong>
    </h3>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
    <form class="form-signin text-center" role="form">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in to Continue</h2>
        <input type="email" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Domain ID" autofocus required>
        <input type="password" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Password" required>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

working code : [jsBin : Centered Login Div](http://jsbin.com/xoqepe/2/)